# ROS VS Code Debugger unrecognized remap tag in <include> tag

Tags: roslaunch, package.xml, remap, remapping, vscode

I am using [ROS extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-iot.vscode-ros) and I have organized my launch files based on [Roslaunch tips for large projects](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects). I have 2 main launch files, one that I launch from the linux terminal, and one via the launch.json in VS Code (both shown below).

Launched in VS code: master_rag_simulation.launch:

```xml
<launch>

<!-- launch Gazbeo with multiple robots -->

<include file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/launch/multi_karto_gtsam_posfilter.launch"/>

<include file="$(find resource_aware_coordination)/launch/multi_local_comm_nodes.launch"/>

</launch>
```

Launched from terminal: master_rag_sim_terminal.launch:

```xml
<launch>

<!-- launch Gazbeo with multiple robots -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_MAIN_turtlebot3_testzone.launch"/>

<!-- multirobot laser scanner filter on each robot -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/launch/multi_posfilter.launch"/>

<!-- launch move_base for each robot -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/multi_move_base.launch"/>

<!-- launch frontier point exploration nodes on each robot's local OGM -->
<include file="$(find resource_aware_coordination)/launch/exploration_frontier_points.launch"/>


</launch>
```

When I launch this file, particularly the "multi_karto_gtsam_posfilter.launch" file, I get the following error from VS code:

**"Error from roslaunch:
WARN: unrecognized 'remap' tag in  tag"**

This is what my multi_karto_gtsam_posfilter.launch file looks like:

```xml
<launch>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <arg name="output_to_screen" default="screen"/> <!-- New argument for output option -->

  <!-- Launch the gmapping node for Turtlebot 3 with custom namespace -->
  <!-- <group ns="tb3_0"> -->

    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/launch/turtlebot3_karto_gtsam.launch">
      <!-- <arg name="output_to_screen" value="log"/> -->
      <arg name="output_to_screen" value="screen"/>
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_0"/>
      <remap from="/$(arg ns)/scan" to="/$(arg ns)/scan_filtered"/>
    </include>

  <!-- <group ns="tb3_1"> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/launch/turtlebot3_karto_gtsam.launch">
      <arg name="output_to_screen" value="log"/>
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_1"/>
      <remap from="/$(arg ns)/scan" to="/$(arg ns)/scan_filtered"/>
    </include>

  <!-- <group ns="tb3_2"> -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/launch/turtlebot3_karto_gtsam.launch">
      <arg name="output_to_screen" value="log"/>
      <arg name="ns" value="tb3_2"/>
      <remap from="/$(arg ns)/scan" to="/$(arg ns)/scan_filtered"/>
    </include>


  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/multi_map_merge_karto.launch"></include>

  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/rviz/multi_turtlebot3_slam_withpathspose.rviz"/>
  </group>

</launch>
```

What can I do to fix this error so I can continue debugging in VS Code? I see that this error originates from [tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/xmlloader.py](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/master/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/xmlloader.py), line 583. When I run the launch files from my terminal, they work correctly with no errors.